# jQuery and jinja2 .data("") returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, jinja2

the no of items are displayed along with an edit button with each item on clicking edit button the data of button is retrieved in jQuery function but I am getting undefined not the data-id

```
<div>
{% for stock in part_temp.part_stock_set.all %}
    {% with id="list"|concatenate:stock.id  btn_id="btn"|concatenate:stock.id %}
    <div id="{{ id }}">
    {{ stock.entry_date}}
    {{ stock.supplier }}
    {{ stock.amount }}
    {{ stock.remaining }}
        <button id="{{ btn_id }}" type="submit" data-id="{{stock.id}}" onclick="display_popup()" style="position: absolute; right:0;" >edit</button>
    <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

instead of {{stock.id}} I also tried passing other string  but still got undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function display_popup() {
         var name = $(this).data("id");
            window.alert(name);
    }

</script>
```

instead of .data() also tried other like .text() .Val but got nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of current code; `this` in the `display_popup` function refers to `window` object thus its not returning the desired value.

Pass current element context `this` in the inline click handler

```
<button onclick="display_popup(this)">
```

*Script*, Accept it as parameter and use it to get data

```
 function display_popup(elem) {
     var name = $(elem).data("id");
     window.alert(name);
}
```

---

However, I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler. Assign a common class to button.

```
<button class="edit" data-id="{{stock.id}}"  >edit</button>
```

*script*

```
$(function(){
  $('.edit').on('click', display_popup); //this will set as context so you existing method will work
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.edit').on('click', display_popup); //this will set as context so you existing method will work

  function display_popup() {
    var name = $(this).data("id");
    window.alert(name);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="edit" type="submit" data-id="1">edit</button>
```

---

Set the context of function with current element using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
function display_popup() {
  var name = $(this).data("id");
  window.alert(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" data-id="1" onclick="display_popup.bind(this)()">edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, inspect the elements and functions. Try to inspect the HTML and see if the data you need has value. Try to `console.log(this)` on `display_popup` function, You should see the button.

If everything is ok, then try to use `$(this).data()`. It will returns a object with all the data of the element.

If it didn't work (or this case is better for you), use:

```
$(this).attr('data-id')
```

this will return the data-id attribute value.

If none of this works, check your jquery version, but i belive the `attr` will work fine.

----EDIT----

`this` is `undefined` on the `display_popup` function. you need to use `onclick="display_popup(this)"` and then use the parameter to get the element attributes